# No Data from MAVLink_ROS

Tags: ros, mavlink, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I plan to use MAVLink-ROS to read the IMU data from APM2.5. Although it compiles sucessfully by rosmake, the data cannot be received. I use rqt_graph to check the topic and node, but there is no topic or node connected to the node "MAVLink_ros". As a beginner to ROS and Linus, I do not know how to solve the issue. My Ubuntu version is 12.10 and ROS is Hydro. Many thnaks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134986/no-data-from-mavlink_ros/) by [Xiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12726/xiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12726/xiang/) on 2014-03-03**:
Should I rosmake the MAVLink_ROS_PKG in a "built" workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI

you could try this python generator:

https://github.com/posilva/mav2rosgenerator

Best

Pedro

---

Originally posted by [pmosilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/19772/pmosilva/) with karma: 56 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0